# WPF polyline - how to highlight points?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello I have a question about polylines in WPF. How to highlight points in polyline, for example lines are red, but points in **mypolyline.Points** are blue?

Answer (score 2):

A `Polyline` can't do that out of the box, since it renders as a collection of connected line segments only.

You could however add an `ItemsControl` that renders the points like shown below. It uses `Line` elements of zero length, but with round start and end caps to show a dot.

```
<Polyline x:Name="polyline" Points="10,10 50,50 90,10" Stroke="Red"/>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points, ElementName=polyline}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Line Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="5"
                  StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```