# Best practice for showing a lot of lines on grid

Tags: c#, wpf, line, lines

I have a program that reads a file and creates about 1000 points (X,Y coordinate) from the files content. I want to display these points as small crosses on a grid (basically a kind of chart).

this is how it should look like (the green and blue crosses)
[image: This is what I want]

Currently  I am doing this in code behind:

```
foreach (var measurement in collection)
{
  createValueCross(measurement);
}

private void createValueCross(CGM_Measurement measurement)
{
    // set color of line (green when within opt range)
    var crossColor = measurement.Value < mvm.OptMaximum && measurement.Value > mvm.OptMinimum ? Colors.Green : Colors.Blue;

    //create lines
    Line horizontal = new Line();
    Line vertical = new Line();
    vertical.Stroke = horizontal.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(crossColor);
    vertical.StrokeThickness = horizontal.StrokeThickness = 1;

    //get center coordinates
    var x = measurement.Time.getXPosition();
    x = x < 10 ? 10 : x;
    var y = measurement.Value.getYPosition();
    y = y < 10 ? 10 : y;

    // set line start/endpoint +-2 pix from center 
    horizontal.X1 = x - 2;
    horizontal.X2 = x + 2;
    horizontal.Y1 = horizontal.Y2 = y;
    vertical.Y1 = y - 2;
    vertical.Y2 = y + 2;
    vertical.X1 = vertical.X2 = x;

    // draw lines on grid
    chartDataGrid.Children.Add(horizontal);
    chartDataGrid.Children.Add(vertical);

}
```

Is there a good way to this in XAML as well? Like in "Polyline" where you can specify a point collection?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41616789/1136211. Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35776191/1136211

Comment: So I'll have to create an itemscontrol which contains the horzontal and vertical lines and binding it to a point collection?

Comment: I can't tell. Your question is too broad.

Comment: Yes, I guess thats the way to go. Created a little test program and it works. I will post an answer when I am finished. Thanks

Comment: Your approach seems fine by me.  The code is smaller than the XAML example below (though that seems fine too), and your "seeing layout from XML'ish text" skills won't help you much when the data is being plotted anyway.

If you wan't it less Java'ish and more C#'ish, you might want to read up in camel case and Pascal case conventions in C# (or just do what ReSharper tells you to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is the solution:

C# Code:

```
    LinesVM vm;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new LinesVM();
        vm.Lines = new ObservableCollection<test1.MainWindow.LinePoints>();
        SolidColorBrush col = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        vm.Lines.Add(new LinePoints(1, 5, col));
        vm.Lines.Add(new LinePoints(10, 15, col));
        vm.Lines.Add(new LinePoints(41, 45, col));
        vm.Lines.Add(new LinePoints(71, 85, col));

        DataContext = vm;


    }

    public class LinesVM
    {
        private ObservableCollection<LinePoints> _lines;
        public ObservableCollection<LinePoints> Lines
        {
            get { return _lines; }
            set
            {
                if (_lines == value)
                    return;
                _lines = value;
            }
        }

    }

    public class LinePoints:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = (sender, e) => { };

        public LinePoints(double x, double y, SolidColorBrush color)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
            Color = color;
        }

        private SolidColorBrush _color;
        public SolidColorBrush Color
        {
            get { return _color; }
            set
            {
                if (_color == value)
                    return;
                _color = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Color)));
            }
        }

        private double _x1;
        public double X1
        {
            get { return _x1; }
            set
            {
                if (_x1 == value)
                    return;
                _x1 = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(X1)));
            }
        }

        private double _x2;
        public double X2
        {
            get { return _x2; }
            set
            {
                if (_x2 == value)
                    return;
                _x2 = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(X2)));
            }
        }

        private double _y1;
        public double Y1
        {
            get { return _y1; }
            set
            {
                if (_y1 == value)
                    return;
                _y1 = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Y1)));
            }
        }

        private double _y2;
        public double Y2
        {
            get { return _y2; }
            set
            {
                if (_y2 == value)
                    return;
                _y2 = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Y2)));
            }
        }

        private double _y;
        public double Y
        {
            get { return _y; }
            set
            {
                if (_y == value)
                    return;
                _y = value;                    
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Y)));
                Y1 = Y - 2;
                Y2 = Y + 2;
            }
        }

        private double _x;
        public double X
        {
            get { return _x; }
            set
            {
                if (_x == value)
                    return;
                _x = value;                    
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(X)));
                X1 = X - 2;
                X2 = X + 2;
            }
        }

    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SolidColorBrush col = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        vm.Lines.Add(new LinePoints(21, 25, col));
        vm.Lines.Add(new LinePoints(210, 215, col));
        vm.Lines.Add(new LinePoints(241, 145, col));
        vm.Lines.Add(new LinePoints(171, 185, col));
        vm.Lines[1].Color = col;
    }
```

and XAML:

```
 <Grid x:Name="maingrid">
        <Button Height="20" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click_1">click</Button>

        <ItemsControl Name="IC" ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}" Margin="10">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Canvas>
                        <Line Name="horizontal" X1="{Binding X1}" X2="{Binding X2}" Y1="{Binding Y}" Y2="{Binding Y}"
                          StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{Binding Color}"/>
                        <Line Name="vertical" X1="{Binding X}" X2="{Binding X}" Y1="{Binding Y1}" Y2="{Binding Y2}"
                          StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{Binding Color}"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```